# Time Complexity of the recursive for loop code

Tags: c#, time-complexity

I have this code,

```
void Generate(List<string> comb, string prefix, string remaining)
{
       int currentDigit = Int32.Parse(remaining.Substring(0, 1));

            if (remaining.Length == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dictionary[currentDigit].Length; i++)
                {
                    comb.Add(prefix + dictionary[currentDigit][i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dictionary[currentDigit].Length; i++)
                {
                    Generate(comb, prefix + dictionary[currentDigit][i], remaining.Substring(1));
                }
            }
}
```

What is the time complexity of the above code?

Is it Generate is O(n) and that itself is being executed n times so O(n^2)?

dictionary is len = 10 and has phone keypads stored it in. 2 = "abc" etc.

The initial call to this code will be like

Generate(new List(), "", "12345");

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to depend on `dictionary[currentDigit]`, not posted.

Comment: what is `n`? is remaining initial size? I guess your dictionary size is 10 at most.

Comment: Posted the dictionary[size]. FYI - this code is from a answer in SO, so was interested in understanding the time complexity of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume dictionary size is `m` and input string size is `n` (remaining) this will be:

```
T(1) = m + constant;
T(n) = m T(n-1) + O(n) ==> T(n) = O(m^n)
```

In fact in each running of `else` part, you will run m times, function of O(n).

Comment: Sorry I've overlooked that this is recursive method

Comment: @saeeda-amiri - I didn't get your last sentence, how did it change to O(mn^n)? Shouldnt it still stay as O(m^n)

Comment: @parsh yes you are right, I'll edit it as first, but If you want to comment for someone, in his answer or post there is no need to use `@`. Also if this answers your question mark it as answer.

Comment: Sorry posting for the first time, will try to catch up to the rules.

Comment: @parsh no matter dude, and these aren't rule, just hint to do your job faster and cleaner.